# Paste special characters with grid.arrange

Tags: r

I am not sure my question can be addressed but I am trying to paste `★` as a character to a ggplot with a grid.arrange. I am using

```
grid.arrange(pm, bottom = textGrob("'★' P < 0.001, ' ' P > 0.001", rot = 0, hjust = -0.3, vjust = -0.5))
```

I also tried

```
grid.arrange(pm, bottom = textGrob(as.character("'★' P < 0.001, ' ' P > 0.001"), rot = 0, hjust = -0.3, vjust = -0.5))
```

As well as with `paste` command but it didnt work. Instead returns empty square. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Maybe use `\u2605` for the star. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Comment: The question would be better if the example was reproducible and if you included the error message that you are getting.  Please edit it to explain your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Unicode value for the black star.

```
 grid.newpage(); grid.text("\u2605")
```

---

It may be that the font use are using for the text doesn't have a black star character.  Try printing a different character (at least to see if it will plot something):

```
grid.newpage(); grid.text("\u00ff")
```

Then try changing the font.  Under Windows, use:

```
windowsFonts(PlotFont = "Arial Unicode MS")
grid.newpage(); grid.text("\u2605", gp = gpar(fontfamily = "PlotFont"))
```

Under unix-based OSes, swap `windowsFonts` for `X11Fonts` or `quartzFonts`, and pick an font that is installed on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it returns empty square as well.

Comment: @HoHoHo Wildly guessing but I've made this mistake before. Are you actually plotting to file, but thought you were plotting onscreen?  Take a look at `dev.cur()` and `dev.list()`.

Comment: Or by empty square do you mean a substitute for a missing character? (Rather than "my plot is just an empty square with nothing showing".)  In this case, maybe the font you are using just doesn't have a star character.  Trying printing different characters and see if that works.